# Problem while implementing pagination in wordpress query

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have been trying to make a news page with my posts and looking to implement pagination in WordPress.

This is what I tried so far:

```
<div class="page-header" id="page-header=news">
    <h1>News</h1>
</div>

<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post', // Change 'post' to your custom post type if you have one
    'posts_per_page' => 10, // Number of posts to display
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);

if ($query->have_posts()) :
    /* Start the Loop */
    while ($query->have_posts()) :
        $query->the_post();

        /*
         * Include the Post-Type-specific template for the content.
         * If you want to override this in a child theme, then include a file
         * called content-___.php (where ___ is the Post Type name) and that will be used instead.
         */
        get_template_part('template-parts/content', get_post_type());

    endwhile;

    ?>
    <div class="pagination">
        <?php
        the_posts_pagination(array(
            'next_text' => __('Next page', 'mothertongues'),
            'prev_text' => __('Previous page', 'mothertongues'),
        ));
        ?>
    </div>
    <?php

    wp_reset_postdata(); // Reset the post data

else :
    get_template_part('template-parts/content', 'none');
endif;
?>
```

But it's not working, while I am able to get the posts, the pagination in itself does not load.

any help would be super appreaciated.

Comment: try function `paginate_links()` instead

Comment: it worked. appreciated.